# How to check if node globally exists and set condition on it in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm struggling with problem of creating query in Cypher.
Let's use this graph as an example:

```
MERGE(a:Person {name:'Alice', age:38, eyes:'brown'})
MERGE(c:Person {name:'Charlie', age:53, eyes:'green'})
MERGE(d:Person {name:'Daniel', age:54, eyes:'brown'})
MERGE(b:Person {name:'Bob', age:25, eyes:'blue'})
MERGE(a)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
MERGE(a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
MERGE(c)-[:KNOWS]->(d)
MERGE(b)-[:KNOWS]->(d)
```

I would like to have query that returns me nodes with `name = 'Alice'` only if there aren't any nodes with `name = 'Bob'`. So if there is Bob I would like to see no results.

Here is what I've tried:

1) With exists()

```
MATCH p =(n)-[*1..3]->(b)
WHERE n.name = 'Alice' AND NOT EXISTS ((n {name: 'Bob'})-[*1..3]->(b))
RETURN p
```

But it returns all nodes and relationships.

2) With none()

```
MATCH p =(n)-[*1..3]->(b)
WHERE n.name = 'Alice' AND NONE (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x.name = 'Bob')
RETURN p
```

This returned all nodes, without Bob...

3) with any()

```
MATCH p =(n)-[*1..3]->(b)
WHERE n.name = 'Alice' AND NOT ANY (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x.name = 'Bob')
RETURN p
```

But this gave me the same result as above.

I'm running out of ideas how to return Alice only if Bob is not present. 
What I would expect from query is to return Alice when I delete Bob, but when such node exists - nothing.

Any help is appreciated:)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this query :

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:'Alice'})
WHERE NOT (n)-[:KNOWS*..3]-(:Person {name:'Bob'})
RETURN n
```